# Django Session Cookie & Apache Restart Invalidating Cookies?

Tags: django, apache, cookies, session-cookies, django-sessions

My django app works without issue with one strange caveat.

Our settings are essentially basic, out of the box settings with nothing special.

In our settings we recently added the following setting : `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` (set to `True`)

We noticed something odd however and I'm not sure if it's Apache that is doing this or Django - so I'm in need of some help.

If I open a fresh browser that has never been to the site before - I can get logged into the admin. No worries (yet).

I can see that the browser gets and sets the `sessionid` cookie (for my example we will say the value of that cookie is `foo`). I can see that in the `django_session` table the cookie is added there, too. The expire is set for 2 weeks out (default behavior).

If I restart Apache and do a hard refresh on the browser, I can no longer access the `/admin` URL unless I delete the `sessionid` cookie in the browser. I can access the frontend of the site, and it recognizes that I've been logged in before and it works as expected - but I cannot get into the admin any longer.

My questions are as follows:

- Does restarting Apache always, automatically invalidate existing `sessionid` cookies for Django?
- Are there settings in Apache to prevent this from occurring?
- Are the security concerns from this behavior?
- Any idea why the frontend would continue to register it as a logged-in/valid session while the admin would not? We don't explicitly do any cookie checking in the view, but I would figure that if Django doesn't let the `/admin/` get viewed, it would block it elsewhere, too. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Restarting Apache should not have any effect on the cookies set by Django. It is likely there is something else going on which isn't deducible from the information you've provided. You will need to do some additional debugging - e.g., to determine if the request reaches Django at all, and if not, what response is being served to the browser.

Comment: I didn't think it would have an affect - I was kind of hoping someone would come along and say "oh, in Django 3.x this setting does a, b or c", drats. I'm not totally sure how to continue troubleshooting this, but I'll give it a go. I know the request reaches Django, as everything works okay up until I restart Apache - at which point it acts as if the existing cookies in the database are invalidated.